# What happened to these body parts?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

In Deadpool 2, Wade is

> ripped in half by Juggernaut, and is carried home by Domino like a rucksack.

Following scenes show that he is

> growing the lower half of his body back, including legs and other bits...

Did anything happen to the (presumably now surplus to requirements) ripped off body parts that was shown/explained in the film?  I don't recall any mention of what happened to them - did I miss something?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119743/if-you-cut-deadpool-exactly-in-half-which-half-would-regenerate

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D (useful to see that discussion) but I was wondering if there was anything about the removed parts specifically; as in, did they mention anything about what was done with them that I may have missed?

Comment: I don't think they are mentioned in the first movie and probably not the second...which I haven't seen yet.

Comment: @Paulie_D This question is specifically about a scene in the second movie - if you've not seen it yet then I expect there's no way you can answer it I'm afraid...

Comment: He loses body parts in the first one two.

Comment: @m1gp0z If you can screenshot a scene showing that or point to the area in the movie where this is stated, then it's worth posting your own answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## We don't know

You didn't miss anything. Those bodyparts aren't mentioned again after Deadpool is

> ripped in half and then carried home.

They're also not, to my knowledge, shown at any point in the rest of the movie; it's possible they're in the background of some shots in the scenes following that event, but never in a way that draws focus to them (which would happen if they were actually relevant to the plot).